# Matrix $M_1 = M(f', \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B '})$ of $f$

Tags: linear-algebra

$f: \mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_{2}(\mathbb{R}) $

$ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ x_1 + x_3 & x_5 \end{pmatrix}$

1. Determine the basis of $Kerf$
2. Determine a basis of $Imf$
3. Determine the matrix $M_1 = M(f', \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B '})$ of $f$

   ---

1 . $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) \in Kerf \iff f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ x_1 + x_3 & x_5 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

I got $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (0,0,0,x_4,0)$.

A base of $Kerf$ is $(0,0,0,1,0)$.

2. $Imf^= Vect <f(e_1), f(e_2), f(e_3), f(e_4), f(e_5) > = <E_{11}, E_{12}, E_{21}, E_{22}>$

So the family $(E_{11}, E_{12}, E_{21}, E_{22})$ is basis.

with $E_{ij} $ is the elementary matrix.

The coordinate $x_4$ is not on the matrix.

Are my answers correct?

I need help with question 3, too. Thank you.

Comment: $f$ should be a map from $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Comment: For starters: you have ignored  $x_3$ in the kernel. So it should be $(0,0,x_3,x_4,0) \in K$. This mean kernel has dimension $2$. Likewise the image also needs fixing. Because the image can only have dimension $3$.

Comment: @AnuragA I just made a mistake typing. I have just corrected it. Thank you for noticing.

Comment: @Jacob.  Okay that changes things in what I said above. Now with the edited version your answers are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $$f(e_1)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 \\
1 &0\\
\end{bmatrix},f(e_2)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
0 &0\\
\end{bmatrix},f(e_3)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 \\
1 &0\\
\end{bmatrix},f(e_5)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 \\
0 &1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The matrix w.r.t the standard bases should look like $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: You mean the matrix with respect to the basis $(f(e_1) , f(e_2), f(e_3), f(e_5))$ which is the basis of $Imf$, which is$ M (f,\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B'}) $. Right?

Comment: No. I thought that $\mathcal{B'}$ is the standard basis for $M_{2\times2}$

Comment: Ah, that is what I was asked. Thank you.