# Determine a basis of the image and ther kernel of $g$ .

Tags: linear-algebra

$g : \mathcal{M}_2 (\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$ A \rightarrow g(A) = \operatorname{tr}(A)$

1. Determine the basis of $\ker g$
2. Determine the basis of $\operatorname{im} g $
3. Determine the matrix $M (g, \mathcal{B'}, \mathcal{B''})$ with respect to the standard canonical basis $\mathcal{B'}$ and $\mathcal{B''}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ respectively.

---

**1**. $ A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d  \end{pmatrix} \in \ker g \iff \operatorname{tr}(A) = a + d = 0 \iff a = -d $

and , $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & -a \end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} + bE_{12} + cE_{21} $.

A basis of $\ker g$ is $(\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, E_{12}, E_{21})$.

**2**. $\operatorname{Im}g = \operatorname{Vect}\left\langle g \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, g(E_{12}), g(E_{21})\right\rangle = \operatorname{Vect} \langle 0,0,0\rangle = \operatorname{Vect}\langle 0\rangle$

A basis of $\operatorname{im}g $ is $(0)$.

**3**. $M (g, \mathcal{B'}, \mathcal{B''}) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$

Are my answered correct?

Comment: In the first answer, the matrix should be $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, not the identity matrix. Also, since the transformation $g$ is non-zero, it's range  is the whole of $\mathbb R$, so the basis of $Im\  g$ is just $\{1\}$, for example.

Comment: The third one is correct, though.

Comment: You have asked a similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355401/matrix-m-1-mf-mathcalb-mathcalb-of-f a little while ago. Perhaps going through the solutions and the concepts is better than asking similar questions repeatedly.

Comment: @AnuragA I don't have the solution of my problem. I was not sure of my solution, that's why I asked. Sorry if it is against the rules here.